# Finding the equation of more than one tangent line

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I ran into a problem I have no idea how to begin, maybe you guys can help me out. I think maybe it has something to do with parametric equations? But this is just a guess.

Find equations of both the tangent lines to the ellipse $x^2 + 4y^2 = 36$ that pass through the point $(12, 3)$. I can easily find the derivative using implicit differentiation, but what is meant by two tangent lines?

Comment: This is meant: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj6MW.png

Answer (score 4):

Let the point(s) of tangency be $(a,b)$. By implicit differentiation, the slope of the tangent line is $-\frac{a}{4b}$.

But the tangent line has slope $\frac{b-3}{a-12}$. We thus obtain the equation
$$-\frac{a}{4b}=\frac{b-3}{a-12}.$$
This simplifies to $a^2+4b^2-12a-12b=36$.  Use this, together with $a^2+4b^2=36$, to find the points of tangency. Luckily, the algebra is simple. Thank you, problem-setter.

**Remark:** For the *meaning* of "both tangent lines," note that the point $(12,3)$ is **not** on the ellipse, it is outside the ellipse. You know that if we have a circle, and a point $P$ outside the circle, there are two lines tangent to the circle and passing through $P$. The same is true for ellipses, which are just mildly deformed circles.